# SQL: Parsing and summing an associative array stored as varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, sql-server-2012, associative-array

I've got a SQL table storing an associative array as a varchar in this way: `"JOE11,BOB7,CORY3,DAVID2"`. The keys are alpha, the values are numeric, pairs are separated by commas. This seems like a dumb way to store this information but I can't do anything about that at the moment. I need to calculate the sum of the values of the array (11+7+3+2=23, in this example) and then sum that calculation across multiple records.

Any recommendations would be lovely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of

```
Select sum(cast(substring(t2.value,patindex('%[0-9]%',t2.value),20) as int))
from t
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (t.col , ',')  t2 -- sql 2016
```

If you are on lower version, find Jeff Moden's  DelimitedSplit8k()
It's here for example,
[Multiple group split string in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833090/multiple-group-split-string-in-sql)

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2012

Comment: With SQL Server 2012 I was able to use the DelimitedSplit8k() recommended above and got it working.